# Network calls /.well-known/openid-configuration/ and /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have :

- Identity server 4,
- Mvc app with OpenId Connect and Hybrid flow
- WebApi app

Assume user already got cookies with id_token and access token.
Then he calls an action from mvc app:

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
 client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
// call webapi from mvc
 var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5001/api/resource-with-policy");
```

In fiddler i see two calls:

- GET /.well-known/openid-configuration/
- GET /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks

As i assume WebApi sees [Authorize] attribute on action and make these calls.
What's purpose of these calls?

WebApi is configured this way:

````
              .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
              {options.Authority = "<is4-url>";
                  options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                  options.Audience = "Api1";
              });```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JWT token which is signed by Security Token Service in private key. A JWT token is a non-encrypted digitally signed JSON payload which contains different attributes (claims) to identify the user. The signature is the last part of the JWT and needs to be used for verification of the payload. This signature was generated with the algorithm described in the header(`RS256` for example) to prevent unauthorized access.Please refer to [this document](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/jwt/validate-jwt) for more details about JWT token .

To validate signature , firstly we should retrieve and cache the singing tokens (public key) :1)The first call is to the discovery endpoint. It's URL is formed as `/.well-known/openid-configuration` .2) Then you will find lots of metadata here including the  `jwks_uri` endpoint address which will send get request to get the keys to validate the token's signature .

Token signing is implemented according to JSON Web Key spec. Using Key ID and X.509 certificate thumbprint values from the token's header (`kid` and `x5t` parameters respectively) and then find the appropriate public key in the obtained collection of keys to verify the signature with `n(Modulus)` and `e(Exponent)`. [Here](http://codingstill.com/2016/01/verify-jwt-token-signed-with-rs256-using-the-public-key/) is one code sample .

Answer (score 0):

Those are part of the OpenID Connect protocol.
Your API uses the first request to discover parameters it uses for token validation.
That configuration document contains e.g. the valid issuer value to expect in tokens.
The second request is getting the public signing keys for tokens.
That URL is in the first document.

So it's all data used by the API to validate tokens, so you don't need to manually configure them.

Comment: As you wrote 'The second request is getting the public signing keys for tokens'. I need more detailed explanation. I guess this endpoint validates issuer or any else?

Comment: In general the signing keys are downloaded by the app once. Then it has all the data it needs to validate tokens without any requests to IdentityServer. The JWT received by your API has a digital signature. The API can generate that signature as well using the public key, and verify that it matches the signature on the token. This way the API knows the token has not been modified. Then it can check expiry times, issuer, audience, scopes etc.

Comment: From /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks if gets {"kty":"RSA","use":"sig","kid":"c3130a4f920d2a0023dd14cc0ee92ee7","e":"AQAB","n":"--", ","alg":"RS256"} What this verifies?

Comment: Kty is probably key type. RSA means it uses the RSA algorithm, asymmetric encryption. Use=sig means this key is used for digital signatures. Kid is the id of the key, referenced in token header. Alg=RS256 means the specific algorithm is RSA with SHA-256. e and n are the public parameters for RSA. Anyone with those values can verify a signature is valid. If you are interested in specifics of RSA: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Comment: More on the topic is explained here: https://community.auth0.com/t/jwt-signing-algorithms-rs256-vs-hs256/7720/2