# IdentityServer4: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://myServer/.well-known/openid-configuration

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, https, identityserver4

I'm currently working on a **.NET Core 3.1** application with IdentityServer4.

My applications look like this:

- .NET Core 3.1 IdentityServer4 (Windows Server 1 - VM)
- .NET Core 3.1 WebApi (Windows Server 2 - VM)

Both applications run on IIS with a valid wildcard certificate for HTTPS - TLS/SSL.

I use the Authorization Code + PKCE flow.

When I run my applications on localhost it works as a charm, but when I run them on windows server deployed, it seems the Api cannot find the IdentityServer4 Discovery Document and I get this error:

**IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://myServer/env/.well-known/openid-configuration**

The complete error looks like this:

> "message": "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
> connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.",
> "type": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
> "raw": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
> after a period of time, or established connection failed because
> connected host has failed to respond.\r\n   at
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)",
> "stackFrames": [
> {
> "function": "System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
> }
> ]

In my browser I can see the .well-known reference when I call the url: https://myServer/env/.well-known/openid-configuration.

A similar question has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245281/network-calls-well-known-openid-configuration-and-well-known-openid-configu).

In my WebAPI project, I need to use JWTBearer and Cookie schemas. The WebAPI connect options look like this:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(
   options =>
       {
           options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       }).AddJwtBearer(
   options =>
       {
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
           string authority = "https://myAuth.com/env";
           options.Authority = authority;
           options.Audience = "MyApi1";
           options.MetadataAddress = $"{authority}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
           options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
           {
               RequireAudience = true,
               RequireExpirationTime = true,
               ValidateAudience = true,
               ValidateActor = true,
               ValidateLifetime = true,
               ValidateIssuer = true,
               ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
               RoleClaimType = "role",
               NameClaimType = "name"
           };
       })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOpenIdConnect(
      OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
      options =>
          {
              string authority = "https://myAuth.com/env";
              options.Authority = authority;
              options.MetadataAddress = $"{authority}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
              options.ClientId = "Swagger_Docu";
              options.ClientSecret = "secret";
              options.SaveTokens = true;
              options.ResponseType = "code";
              options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
              options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    
              options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    
          });
```

Do you know how to properly obtain the .well-known/openid-configuration from IdentityServer4 in my .NET Core 3.1 API?

Comment: The error message is just a standard timeout message.  You could be failing the TLS authentication which occurs before the HTTP Request.  I would use a sniffer and verify the TLS version to see if you are using TLS 1.2/1.3 (not 1.0/1.1) and if you are getting an HTTP Response.  Check response for status code 200 OK (or 400/500 error).  when was the last time other application was used?  Does it still work?  In June Microsoft did a security update which disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers and client now must use TLS 1.2/1.3.

Comment: Best was of debugging is use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare working with non working.  You are not specifically in c# specifying the TLS version.  So the default TLS version depends on the version of Net and the version of windows.  A IIS is a old operating system and probably default to TLS 1.0 which will not work.  You have to modify c# code to add the TLS version.

Comment: I use a TLS/SSL 1.2 certificate and the connection is valid and encrypted.

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 seems to use TLS/SSL 1.3 as default - can this difference TLS/SSL 1.2 and TLS/SSL 1.3 cause an issue?

Comment: Yes.  The encryption modes can be different (see wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) or the server can be configured to accept one and not the other.  Usually Microsoft every time a new Net is released they update the default to the latest and greatest so users old code breaks.

Comment: This is HTTPS issue as other comment mentioned as well. Check your IPs too, here is an example issue like yours https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3039#issuecomment-466289444 . Also you dont need to set `MetadataAddress`, its value is used just if Authority is not set, Ref: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerPostConfigureOptions.cs#L35 & https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectPostConfigureOptions.cs#L77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice is to do a simple HttpClient "are you there, test request" to your IdentiyServer, just to make sure you can reach it. Or perhaps also if you are fancy, allow the client to wait and retry this ping for a few minutes before giving up. Then you can much more easily see in the logs at startup if you have some connectivity problems. Perhaps do both a HTTP and a HTTPS request to make sure both works as well.-

You could in IdentityServer just let your homepage http://youridentityserver/ request return some static text, like

(in your HomeController)

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if (_environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // only show in development
        return View();
    }

    _logger.LogInformation("Homepage is disabled in production. Returning 404.");
    return NotFound("Service OK");
}
```

Then look for the "Service OK" in your client before your webapp start up.